# Импорт Данных из ввода/справочника 1С

Tags: 1с

1.Есть поле ввода в общей форме, как перенести данный вбитые в поле в справочник?
2. Как взять данные из справочника и выводить их значение в таблицу в общей форме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Функция УппСоздатьКонтрагента(Наименование, Полное, ИНН, КПП, ЮрАдрес, ФактАдрес)
    //                                                           Метаданные.Справочники.Контрагенты, 
    УникальныйКод = УппПолучитьНовыйКод("КР", "Код", 9); // Метаданные.Справочники.Контрагенты.Реквизиты.Код.Тип.КвалификаторыСтроки.Длина);
    НовыйЭлемент = Справочники.Контрагенты.СоздатьЭлемент();
    НовыйЭлемент.Код = УникальныйКод;
    НовыйЭлемент.Наименование = Наименование;
    НовыйЭлемент.НаименованиеПолное = Полное;
    НовыйЭлемент.ЮрФизЛицо = ?(10=СтрДлина(СокрЛП(ИНН)), Перечисления.ЮрФизЛицо.ЮрЛицо, Перечисления.ЮрФизЛицо.ФизЛицо);
    НовыйЭлемент.ИНН = ИНН;
    НовыйЭлемент.КПП = КПП; 
    НовыйЭлемент.Покупатель = Истина;
    НовыйЭлемент.Поставщик = Истина;    
    // Группа контрагентов "К-телеком"
    НовыйЭлемент.Родитель = УппГруппаКонтрагента("К-телеком");
    Если КПП="" И (НовыйЭлемент.ЮрФизЛицо = Перечисления.ЮрФизЛицо.ЮрЛицо) Тогда
        ОбщегоНазначения.ЗаполнитьКППпоИНН(ИНН, НовыйЭлемент.КПП);
        Сообщить("КПП для ЮрЛица установлен автоматически !");
    КонецЕсли;

    НовыйЭлемент.ОбменДанными.Загрузка = Истина;  // Показываем что элемент заводится Программно.
    НовыйЭлемент.Записать();
    НовыйЭлемент.ГоловнойКонтрагент = НовыйЭлемент.Ссылка;
    НовыйЭлемент.Записать();
    Сообщить("Новый КОД = " + УникальныйКод + "   ИНН = " + СокрЛП(ИНН) + "   КПП = " + СокрЛП(КПП));
    Сообщить("Юридический адрес:" + ЮрАдрес);
    Сообщить("Фактический адрес:" + ФактАдрес);

    Возврат НовыйЭлемент.Ссылка;
КонецФункции
```